# Cannot make function read Double array

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, pointers

So i have a piece of code where i want to store 5 random names no longer than 10 letters each

```c
void printname(char *s);

int main() {
  char NAME[10][5];
  int NAMECOUNTER=0;
  while(NAMECOUNTER<5) {
    scanf("%s",NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);
    printname(&NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);
    NAMECOUNTER++;
  }
}

void printname(char *s) {
 printf("Hello %s\n",*s);
 return;
}

And lets say i want the name to print itself through function Printname. Why does this not work and prints "Hello (null)"?
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see

```
char NAME[10][5];
```

Should be

```
char NAME[5][11];
```

This way you're declaring 5 name slots, each with 10 char max. The extra space is for the string null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
void printname(char *s) {
 printf("Hello %s\n",*s); 
 return;
}
```

and you need

```
void printname(char *s) {
 printf("Hello %s\n",s);  // Took off the * from the *s
 return;
}
```

because s is already your pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I give 6 glitches to fix. See comments prefacing `#<num>`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printname(char *s);

int main() {
    char NAME[5][11] = {0}; // #1 value initialize to zero
                            // #2 the second dimension should be 11, since 10 letters plus null-character
    int NAMECOUNTER=0;
    while(NAMECOUNTER<5) {
        scanf("%10s",NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);  // #3 %10s width specifier, limit the length of name up to 10 character long
        while ( (ret = getchar()) != '\n') ; // #4 trim exceeding characters
        printname(NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);  // #5 no &
        NAMECOUNTER++;
    }
}

void printname(char *s) {
    printf("Hello %s\n",s); // #6 no *
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even print anything to me, it just freeze and closes. Also it's not so clear.

You are mistyping the "NAME" array inside printname. This function does not have a return value, since it has a void return, so you shouldn't type any return. Also you can save some code lines writing it **before** main function which is the best practice:

```
void printname(){
//todo
}

int main(){
return 0;
}
```

This is a better way to implement your function:

```
void printname(char Names[5][11], int index){
    printf("Hello %s\n", Name[index]);
}
```

You could replace the while structure with **for** structure, since it is the best application for the purpose in that case:

**Your code piece:**

```
while(NAMECOUNTER<5) {
    scanf("%s",NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);
    printname(&NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);
    NAMECOUNTER++;
}
```

*You don't have to put "&" in the first argument of printname.*

**Best:**

```
for(NameCounter = 0; NameCounter < 5; NameCounter++){
        scanf("%s",NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);
        printname(NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);
}
```

Also make sure to keep your code indentation clear. This is your final code:

```
void printname(char Names[][11], int index){
    printf("Hello %s\n", Names[index]);
}

int main(){
    
    char NAME[5][11];
    int NAMECOUNTER;;
    for(NAMECOUNTER = 0; NAMECOUNTER < 5; NAMECOUNTER++){
        
        scanf("%s", NAME[NAMECOUNTER]);
        printname(NAME, NAMECOUNTER);
    }
}
```